# DOMDocument not found

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to code my own "HTML Generator" so i won't have to write HTML as string anymore, but the problem is that PHP doesn't recognize the DOMDocument class, it tries to load a Class with the name DOMDocument in the same namespace, which throws the error, I tried adding the backslah but no luck, here's my code :

```
<?php

namespace Services\HtmlGenerator;

use \DOMDocument;

/**
* Services\HtmlGenerator\Html
*/
class Html extends DOMDocument
{

    function __construct(){
         parent::__construct('1.0','iso-8859-1' );
         $this->formatOutput = true;
    }

    public function createInput($value, $name, $class = null)
    {
        $input = $this->createElement('input');
        $input->setAttribute('value', $value);
        $input->setAttribute('name', $name);
        $input->setAttribute('class', $class);
        return $input;
    }
}
```

the code of the action in the controller that uses this class :

```
<?php

namespace ModuleX\RemoteControllers;

use Services\HtmlGenerator\Html;
//...

class RemoteXController extends RemoteController
{
 //...
public function action()
{
    $html = new Html;
    $elem = $html->createInput('test', 'test', 'test');
    $html->appendChild($elem);
    return $html->saveHTML();
```

Here's the error message :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Services\HtmlGenerator\DOMDocument' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\services\htmlGenerator\Html.php on line 10
```

I'm using `XAMPP 1.8.3 with PHP 5.5.15` on a Windows 7 machine.

I also want to mention that when I use `$html = new \DOMDocument;` in my controller it works just fine.

Comment: Does the class DOMDocument use the namespace Services\HtmlGenerator?

Comment: @user1187347, nop, I'm just using it in that scope.

Comment: You might need to specify the namespace of the class DOMDocument e.g. class Html extends \DOMDocument

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work :/

Comment: Is the DOMDocument class definitely being loaded?

Comment: Yup which is really weird, when I try to instanciate a new DOMDocument object in my controller it works just fine.

Comment: Can you provide the error displayed when using the leading backslash?

Comment: @user1187347 it gives the same error it's like the backslash is not being interpreted, I updated the code in the question. Thanks a lot for you time.

Answer (score 1):

Add `use \DOMDocument;` after the namespace line

Comment: Thanks @RichardBernards but I'm still getting the same error :/ . by the way, I'm using `XAMPP 1.8.3 with PHP: 5.5.15` on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @teeyo try it with the extra slash (added in answer)

Comment: Still no luck, I even added the ` as DOMDocument` 

    `<?php

    namespace Services\HtmlGenerator;

    use \DOMDocument;

    /**
    * Class Services\HtmlGenerator\Html
    */
    class Html extends DOMDocument
    {`

Answer (score 1):

When extending a class from another namespace, you need to use a fully qualified name for the `extends` statement. For example:

```
<?php

namespace Services\HtmlGenerator;

class Html extends \DOMDocument
{
...
}
```

Note the leading backslash on the `extends` statement

Comment: thanks @user1187347 but the namespace of the DOMDocument is the "\", meaning when I write '\DOMDocument' I'm already providing the fully qualified name for the class. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, that should do it so long as you use the leading backslash!

Answer (score 1):

This can often be caused by not having the right modules installed for PHP. If your server is running a Linux distro (like CentOS) that supports YUM, you can install it with a command like this:

`yum install php-xml.x86_64`

Then simply restart apache (eg: `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`) and it should be ready to go.